# Visual Studio .NET has detected that ASP.NET applications and services are locked down in IIS

Tags: iis-6, lockdown

Getting this error when try to compile a .net 1.1 website:

> Visual Studio .NET has detected that ASP.NET applications and services are locked down in IIS. You can run the IIS Security Lockdown Wizard to change lockdown status

How I "unlockdown" it in IIS6, where is this fabled IIS Lockdown wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this answer, it's located on [msdn here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817267) in short

- Open IIS6
- Click "Web Service Extensions"
- Change ASP.NET v1.1.4322 from **prohibited** to **allowed**